# PSPICE monte carlo

Tags: pspice, monte-carlo

I am trying to do a monte carlo simulation using PPSICE(Orcade/Cadence 16.6). Most of the tutorials I see do the Monte Carlo using Orcad Capture(through the schematic approach). I would like to do all in code. Using the text editor in PSPICE.

I know that there exists a .MC command for it.
Are there any simple tutorials for Monte Carlo (code examples only)? Also, I am trying to do a temperature analysis of the said circuit from -10 to 43 Celcius.

Comment: I advise you to leave the temperature sim. out for the moment because MC is complex and it **will** confuse you. Just do a simple .DC simulation and combine that with MC. Then, after you understand what's going on, introduce temperature. Do both at the same time and you will get lost/not understand. I guarantee it, I know, I've been there :-)

Comment: I did a .MC analysis of a voltage dividor and I got this in the output - Mean deviation = 0, Sigma = 0.

My code is this -
R8 3 5 RMOD1 133K 
.MODEL RMOD1 RES(R=1,TC1=.01,Lot=1) 
R9 5 4 RMOD 12K 
.MODEL RMOD RES(R=1,TC1=.01,lot = 1) 
.tran 1m 100m 10m
.mc 10 tran V(5) Ymax List 
.print DC V(5)
.probe
.end

I have not given any seed value. What is it ? And how can I give a value ?

Comment: The deviation = 0 means that there is no spread, maybe the model does not have any spread or it is set to zero.

Comment: How can I give a spread to the model. I have the resistors specified as models with TC1 values and also their tolerances. So, is it possible to still get a 0 deviation ? Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Have you read: https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwikre7nuYHLAhXEDg8KHW1eAiUQFggwMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seas.upenn.edu%2F~jan%2Fspice%2FPSpice_UserguideOrCAD.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEyTmG8kXtNRxFG0fcejwN-sq53Ag&sig2=Q4-in8zmGXAMkNUKQUNShA&bvm=bv.114733917,d.ZWU  Chapter 13 ? MC cannot be explained here, it is all explained in the manual.

Comment: Any tutorials please ? Am using the code version of PSPICE. Not much code examples for Monte Carlo.

Comment: You want to use code, tutorials is for people that use the GUI. Real coders don't need tutorials ;-)

Comment: Yes I want to use code please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35914/discussion-between-board-man-and-fakemoustache).